# How to use ROS Mobile for ROS2

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS1 I used to use my mobile phone as a controller using the ROS Mobile Android application. Can the same application be used for ROS 2? If not, is there a way to use my mobile phone to publish/subscribe and visualise topics in ROS2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406537/how-to-use-ros-mobile-for-ros2/) by [tsadarsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/70847/tsadarsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2022-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

Currently ROS-Mobile does not support communication with ROS 2. It will (hopefully) in the nearer future.
There are however some good resources to take a look at for interversion communication like the ros1_bridge on Github: https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge

Kind regards,
One of the contributors of ROS-Mobile

---

Originally posted by [Schneewittchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/51156/schneewittchen/) with karma: 51 on 2022-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0